# Getting error while trying to deploy NextJS in Vercel, RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, next.js13

**Getting error while trying to deploy NextJS in Vercel.**

Local "*npm run build*" and "*npm run start*" is working without any issue. But for the same codebase facing deployment error in Vercel.

Using NextJS V*14.0.1*, even tried with V*13.4.12* & V*13.4.7* also but no luck, getting same error.

Have implemented Server Action wherever required also, e.g. redirect and async functions.

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/sitemap.xml". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
 ⚠ Entire page /404 deopted into client-side rendering. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering /404

   Generating static pages (15/31) 
 ⚠ Entire page /about deopted into client-side rendering. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering /about
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11) {
  cause: RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header
      at AsyncWriter.end (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10355:19)
      at writeIterable (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10263:16) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH'
  }
}
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11) {
  cause: RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header
      at AsyncWriter.end (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10355:19)
      at writeIterable (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10263:16) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH'
  }
}
Error occurred prerendering page "/about". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
 ⚠ Entire page /disclaimer deopted into client-side rendering. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering /disclaimer
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11) {
  cause: RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header
      at AsyncWriter.end (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10355:19)
      at writeIterable (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10263:16) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH'
  }
}
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11) {
  cause: RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header
      at AsyncWriter.end (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10355:19)
      at writeIterable (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10263:16) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH'
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me with the above error resolution?

Answer (score 0):

For the above problem, error was occurring because of problem in environment variable.

For one my environment, value was not set properly.

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_URL was set as https://${VERCEL_URL}/
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL was set as ${NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/api
```

as a result NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL was returning value as 'https://xyz.vercel.app//api', there was an extra '/' before the api in the url.

Fixing the environment variable as below solved the problem

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL was set as ${NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}api
```